# Escaping $ in Qt Creator's Code Snippet

Tags: escaping, qt-creator, code-snippets

In Qt Creator snippets, how do I work around `$` symbol being replaced? According to [this document](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-completing-code.html), variables are referenced by surrounding their names with `$` like this: `$variable$`. However, what I am trying to do is to have a license snippet that also has SVN Id tag in it, for example:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 1831 Vasiliy Pupkin & Co <vasiliy.pupkin@county.province.earth>
 * Do not even look at this code.
 *
 * $Id$
 */
```

I have tried `$$Id$$`, `\$Id\$` but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Arg, you are right. This is embarrassing and needs to get fixed! Bugreport is here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-8450

Comment: @TobiasHunger: Thanks. Mind putting that as an answer?

Comment: Not befor that is fixed:-)

Comment: @TobiasHunger: Is it fixed yet? :)

Comment: Checked the bug report, the fix should be present in QtCreator version 3.0.0+

Answer (score 1):

You have to write  `\\$Id\\$`.

I had the same issue and could not find something in the documentation. So I tried some patterns. Double backslash was the solution.